# How to configure number of results in Kibana 4

Tags: kibana-4

We are using elasticsearch + kibana 4 for central logging system. But in dashboard (in a "search" table) I have only 10 pages of results by 50 entries. Because our system is composed of several applications cooperating each other 500 logs entries is often too little.
Is it possible to configure number of results (per page and/or number of pages) in kibana 4? In kibana 3 I could configure this in dashboard settings, but I cannot find any options in Kibana 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, not sure what you mean with "search table". Are we talking about a "data-table"-type visualization, or something that has to do with the "discovery" tab, or something entirely different ?

The former has following param :

Settings > Object > yourDataTable > edit

```
"type": "table",
  "params": {
    "perPage": 10
  }
```

The latter has following :

Settings > Advanced

```
discover:sampleSize (Default: 500)
```

(PS : sorry about posting an Answer instead of commenting, I don't have enough rep to add comment to your question)

Comment: I am not sure what is the correct name :). In the discovery I can save as a "search" and then in a dasbhoard I can add this "search" as a table. And this is what I mean. I want to change the number of records in a table that was added to the dashboard. Thanks for the answer I will try at Monday.

Comment: Oh ok I get it. I don't think you can change the 50 per pages, but changing "discover:sampleSize" will affect the number of pages available.

Comment: Yes thanks for the answer I just tried changing sampleSize. Altough I cannot change how many results per page I get it is enough for me to have more results in total (-> more pages).